# KeyError at /docker/auth/ django 1.11 forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to grab and display a django form data which is comping through POST request, but I'm stuck at KeyError for one go my field name,

Here's the error:

```
KeyError at /docker/auth/
'docker_name'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/docker/auth/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'docker_name'
Exception Location: /Users/abdul/Documents/IGui/dockerDep/views.py in post, line 21
Python Executable:  /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
```

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class DockerAuth(models.Model):
    docker_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    docker_pass = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Here's my forms.py:

```
from django.forms import forms
from .import models

class DockerAuthForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('docker_name', 'docker_pass')
        model = models.DockerAuth
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms


class DockerAuth(CreateView):
form_class = forms.DockerAuthForm

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'dockerDep/docker_login.html', {})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    lform = forms.DockerAuthForm(request.POST)
    context = {}
    if lform.is_valid():
        data = lform.cleaned_data
        name = data['docker_name']
        password = data['docker_pass']
        context = {
            "form": lform,
            "uname": name,
            "upass": password
        }
    return render(request, 'dockerDep/response.html', context)
```

Here's my HTML template form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOCKER</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="docker_name" title="Name">
        <input type="password" name="docker_pass" title="Password">. 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the model?

Comment: There's no point using `CreateView` if you override `get` and `post`. You lose all the functionality of the view. In any case, it's confusing to use `CreateView` if you don't actually create anything. It would be better to subclass [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) and override `form_valid`. Or, if you want to define `get` and `post`, simply subclass `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `ModelForm` should fix the `KeyError`. In `forms.py`:

- Change `from django.forms import forms` to `from django import forms`
- Change `class DockerAuthForm(forms.Form)` to `class DockerAuthForm(forms.ModelForm)`